# Why is js thinking my array is not an array in some environments?

Tags: javascript

I am running some Javascript in a JVM browser. I have declared a prototype method to help me push into very large arrays

```js
Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array) {
    if (other_array === Array)
        other_array.forEach(function (v) { this.push(v) }, this);
    else
        console.log("not an array");
}
```

The way it works when called is:

```js
arrayA.extend(arrayB);
```

I know that I am extending arrays. In one environment, all is well. In a different environment, the method thinks arrayB is not an array, which is wrong.

Any clues?

Edit: The array check was actually failing in both environments. My issue was a JDK related error thrown in the forEach loop that went away after updating my JDK

Comment: `if(other_array === Array) other_array.forEach(...)` `Array` is not an array, like the blueprint of an car is not a car.

Comment: Please take a moment to read through https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to understand how you should have formatted your code blocks.

Comment: In which environment does this work? I'm skeptical, because `other_array === Array` is not a valid way to check whether something is an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(other_array === Array)` will pretty much *never* work, unless what you pass is actually the `window.Array` constructor, eg:

```
arrayA.extend(Array); // this will fulfill the `if`, but it will then throw an error
// because the Array constructor has no forEach method
```

Array instances will never fulfill `=== Array`.

But you can use `Array.isArray` instead, which is a reliable, cross-environment way to check if something is an array:

```
Array.prototype.extend = function (other_array) {
    if(Array.isArray(other_array)) {
        other_array.forEach(function(v) {this.push(v)}, this);
    } else {
        console.log("not an array");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the array check is ok now. The prototype function still throws an error in one enviornment

Comment: I figured it out after looking at a java log file. It was a java bug, it went away after updating my JRE